# SharePoint Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to create a Web Part with security-trimmed links for a MOSS Publishing Intranet Portal. The idea is that their logged-in user name is checked against a custom provider to determine their permissions for a particular link and the hyperlinks would be rendered based on this.

What would be a good approach for something like this? In particular, is it possible to inherit from the "Summary Links" Web Part to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @Abs,

I have to use a custom provider as the links go to secure Web applications on another server. The base classes for using this provider are already written, so my plan was to add the DLLs to SharePoint and reference then from my new Web Part. Hopefully, this should work...

Comment: The solution to this was to create a custom xml file with an attribute indicating if roles were applied or not for a particular application link - and if so, another attribute containing the role name. The code would then check the custom membership store using the logged-in users network identity for authorization checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to create a custom xml file with an attribute indicating if roles were applied or not for a particular application link - and if so, another attribute containing the role name. The code would then check the custom membership store using the logged-in users network identity for authorization checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to have the custom provider to check permissions, you could just apply SharePoint permissions to the individual items in a list. Then, the list views would be trimmed automatically. Also, if you wanted to write your own web part to  display them, you could use a CAML query to retrieve the items, and the results would also automatically be trimmed by the current user's permissions.

If you do have to use a custom provider for permissions, I'm not much help. ;-)